# How to wrangle multiple explicit conversion functions?

Tags: c++, vector

I wonder if anyone could explain the following to me?

I have a class A which has a `std::vector` as a member variable.  I'd like to be able to use explicit conversion functions get ...

either ... a reference to that vector, so I can change its contents

or ... a const reference to that vector, so I can examine it but not change it

ideally ... a copy of the vector would be nice, too

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using BoolColumn = std::vector<bool>;
using BoolColumnReference = BoolColumn&;
using BoolColumnConstReference = BoolColumn const &;

class A
{
public:
  A(BoolColumn&& bVec) : m_bools(std::move(bVec)) {}

  explicit operator BoolColumn () {
    std::cout << "  Inside BoolColumn converter" << std::endl;
    return m_bools;
  }

  explicit operator BoolColumnReference () {
    std::cout << "  Inside BoolColumnReference converter" << std::endl;
    return m_bools;
  }

  explicit operator BoolColumnConstReference () const {
    std::cout << "  Inside BoolColumnConstReference converter" << std::endl;
    return m_bools;
  }

private:
  BoolColumn m_bools;
};

int main()
{
  BoolColumn bVec({true, false, true, false, true, false});

  A a(std::move(bVec));

  BoolColumn bc(a);
  BoolColumn bc2 = (BoolColumn)a;
  BoolColumn bc3 = BoolColumn(a);
  BoolColumn bc4 = static_cast<BoolColumn>(a);

  BoolColumn & bcr(a);
  BoolColumn & bcr2 = (BoolColumnReference)a;
  BoolColumn & bcr3 = BoolColumnReference(a);
  BoolColumn & bcr4 = static_cast<BoolColumnReference>(a);
  bcr[0] = false;

  BoolColumn const & bccr(a);
  BoolColumn const & bccr2 = (BoolColumnConstReference)a;
  BoolColumn const & bccr3 = BoolColumnConstReference(a);
  BoolColumn const & bccr4 = static_cast<BoolColumnConstReference>(a);
  // bccr[0] = false; // ... error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value (good!)
}
```

All my efforts to go into different converters fail ... I always end up in the "BoolColumnReference" converter

Where am I going wrong, please?

Comment: Well, if you called your `BoolColumnConstReference` conversion function on `const A` object, you would see it getting called (the compiler chooses which of those overloads to call based on the const-ness of the method). On the other hand, your usages of `BoolColumn` function fail to compile with the reason (`No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous`) on MSVC. My guess that it is conflicting with the `BoolColumnReference`, and your compiler chooses it implicitly, without warning you.

Comment: Thanks, @AlgirdasPreidžius.  It all compiles here on MSVC (2015, update 1).  

I see your const A point ... I was hoping to _not have one such (some methods would change it, some would not be allowed to).  Maybe I can't

Comment: well, I was compiling it under MSVC 2013, so probably the logic relating to ambiguity of methods was changed :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
};

class B {
public:
  explicit operator A () {
    std::cout << "COPY" << std::endl;
    return a;
  }

  explicit operator A& () {
    std::cout << "REF" << std::endl;
    return a;
  }

  explicit operator const A& () const {
    std::cout << "CONST REF" << std::endl;
    return a;
  }

 private:
   A a;
 };

int main() {
  B b;
  A a(b);
}
```

I've created a simplified version of the code above to illustrate what is happening here. When we call the A constructor to create an instance of A from an instance of B, we are actually calling the copy constructor of A with the arguments returned from the user defined conversion operator.

So the order of operations:

1. Check for constructor in A which takes type B
2. Use copy constructor with value returned from conversion operator.

There is no copy constructor defined in type A which takes a type B. So the implicit copy constructor is used

```
A(A& a) {
}
```

meaning that we are always going to use the operator A& because this is the correct type for the implicit conversion operator.

However if we declare B::a as const then the const copy constructor in A will be called meaning the program will print "CONST REF".

Comment: It's as simple as that !!  :)  Thanks a lot